# http request from inside rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, controller, request

I want to let one of my controllers make an http request from within my controller, to "get" and parse an xml, that I can then display in my view. Sounds like an easy task..

```
require 'net/http'

class Profile::EventTypesController < ProfileController

  def index
    url =  URI.parse('instagram.com')
    req = Net::HTTP.new(url, 80)
    res = req.get('/my_account')

    xml = res.body
    @feed = Feedjira::Feed.parse xml
    ...

    ...
  end
end
```

As soon as I try it out it wont work, showing the following exception:

```
WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError at /de
Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: GET http://instagram.com/my_account with headers {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}

stub_request(:get, "http://instagram.com/partyguerilla").
with(headers: {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
to_return(status: 200, body: "", headers: {})
```

Is there any way to enable "REAL HTTP connections" from within my controller? When I google, it is all about mocking stubs and doing this from within tests.. Did someone experience the same before?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Gemfile for `gem webmock`. It should be included only within the test group, not development.

```
group :test do
  gem 'webmock'
end
```

the same applies to `rspec-rails` gem. See this [issue](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/issues/414#issuecomment-56936918)

Comment: What is also working if you cant change your config -> you can set "WebMock.allow_net_connect!" before and "WebMock.disable_net_connect!" the piece of code you want to enable the request for! Hope this helps someone..